# How to use hang indent to write this paragraph?

Tags: indentation

I want to write a paragraph like the one in the picture and indent all the lines but the first one. How can do this?

[image: example]

Comment: Uh, use `\hangindent=3em` or some other width.

Answer (score 3):

You can set TeX primitive registers `\leftskip` and `\parindent` to appropriate values. This setting is valid for all paragraphs or for all paragraphs in the group:

```
\bgroup
\leftskip=2em \parindent=-\leftskip

paragraph...

paragraph...

paragraph...
\par\egroup
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{shortvrb}
\MakeShortVerb{\|}
\begin{document}

\hangindent=4pc\hangafter=1
|\frontmatter| should be the very first command after the start of the
document body (|\begin{document}|). It will stretch page numbering to
Roman numerals and sections will be non-enumerated as if you were
using the starred sectioning commands (for example, |\chapter*{Preface}|)
but the sections will still show up in the table of contents.

\end{document}
```

[image]

If there is only one paragraph for the description of `\frontmatter`, then use `\hangindent` and `\hangafter`.

If there are two or more paragraphs, you can use the `list` environment or higher-level developed package `enumitem`.